# Identify SMD - top marking "0107" SOT23

Tags: transistors, identification

I need to know the specification of the transistor (probably mosfet but I don't sure) [image]

Comment: Are you sure it's even a transistor, and not a dual diode or more complicated IC?

Comment: If you don't make a diagram it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I found is [LMTL1P10](https://www.leiditech.com/u_file/file/products/2212/12/b45352e9ee.pdf) P-channel MOSFET from Shanghai Leiditech Electronic.

Unfortunately I didn't find any picture and I never seen products from this brand. Confirmation or not from other people is welcomed.

[image]